# asp:hiddenfield is breaking my viewstate

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

In a very large application, with a deep nesting of user controls (a sharepoint application to be accurate), I have in an ascx control :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedLCID" runat="server" />
```

and in the code behind :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uint uLcid = (uint)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID;
    hdnSelectedLCID.Value = uLcid.ToString();
}
```

However, when I render my page, I got an obscure error :

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

If I remove the hidden field, the problem disappears.

Can someone explain me why?

PS: the error message is always leading to a some well known issue: missing or inconsistent encryption key in the config file. Here I have a correct setup. So this is not the root of the issue.

Another way I found to make the problem disappear is to disable the event validation (by adding `eventValidation="false"` on the `<pages>` node of my web.config. But I think this is not a good practice

Comment: +1 very interesting issue. I don't find any logical explanation for this other than a bug in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know the exact solution for your problem, but i guess you need to stop using asp.net control "asp:HiddenField" and try to use ordinary html input with type hidden that runat server.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSelectedLCID" runat="server"/>
```

then you can access this control properties from code behind simply like "asp:HiddenField" control.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uint uLcid = (uint)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID;
    hdnSelectedLCID.Value = uLcid.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I've found several ways of working around the issue (removing the control, using a pure client side hidden field, etc.). My question is actually **why?** and not **how?**